# Ubuntu kmalloc Segmentation Fault

Tags: 16.04

A running container got deleted automatically.

We had a large container running on an Ubuntu server and all of a sudden the container disappeared

- O.S : VERSION=16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- Docker: version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
- Storage Driver: aufs
- Observation: We noticed high memory utilization on the host on that particular day, almost 100%, and the utilization started just 30 minutes before the container disappear incident

The logs captured during the analysis from various sources are given below

`apport.log`:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 195722) Thu Jan 10 01:26:24 2019: 2 18446744073709551615, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 195722) Thu Jan 10 01:26:24 2019: ignoring implausibly big core limit, treating as unlimited
ERROR: apport (pid 195722) Thu Jan 10 01:26:25 2019: executable: /sbin/auplink (command line “auplink /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ad9ab9225c557c10acf97aab3ae2f57fe56f0ad2fbae1798485b48b627a1f198 flush”)
```

`journel.log`:

```
Jan 10 01:26:23 xxxxxx dockerd[5506]: time=“2019-01-10T02:26:23-05:00” level=info msg=“shim reaped” id=8bdd4adeda1b84cc59cbd474d58a19bd2a8e97e63978e0d58f4bc7f3ce3a37e3
Jan 10 01:26:23 xxxxxxx dockerd[5506]: time=“2019-01-10T02:26:23.683906749-05:00” level=info msg=“ignoring event” module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 10 01:26:25 xxxxxxx dockerd[5506]: time=“2019-01-10T02:26:25.020765635-05:00” level=warning msg=“Couldn’t run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ad9ab9225c557c10acf97aab3ae2f57fe56f0ad2fbae1798485b48b627a1f198” error=“signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)” storage-driver=aufs
```

`Kernel.log`:

```
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx kernel: [2834598.543878] docker0: port 1(veth0c49618) entered disabled state
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxx kernel: [2834598.544926] docker0: port 1(veth0c49618) entered disabled state
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx kernel: [2834598.547121] device veth0c49618 left promiscuous mode
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx kernel: [2834598.547124] docker0: port 1(veth0c49618) entered disabled state
Jan 10 02:26:24 xxxxxx kernel: [2834599.394252] auplink[195721]: segfault at 7ffd0d1a1108 ip 00007f06362775b9 sp 00007ffd0d1a1110 error 6 in libc-2.23.so[7f063617e000+1c0000]
```

`Syslog.log`:

```
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx dockerd[5506]: time=“2019-01-10T02:26:23-05:00” level=info msg=“shim reaped” id=8bdd4adeda1b84cc59cbd474d58a19bd2a8e97e63978e0d58f4bc7f3ce3a37e3
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx dockerd[5506]: time=“2019-01-10T02:26:23.683906749-05:00” level=info msg=“ignoring event” module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxxx kernel: [2834598.509967] veth5b6df3a: renamed from eth0
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxxx kernel: [2834598.543878] docker0: port 1(veth0c49618) entered disabled state
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxxxx kernel: [2834598.544926] docker0: port 1(veth0c49618) entered disabled state
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx kernel: [2834598.547121] device veth0c49618 left promiscuous mode
Jan 10 02:26:23 xxxxxx kernel: [2834598.547124] docker0: port 1(veth0c49618) entered disabled state
Jan 10 02:26:24 xxxxxxx kernel: [2834599.394252] auplink[195721]: segfault at 7ffd0d1a1108 ip 00007f06362775b9 sp 00007ffd0d1a1110 error 6 in libc-2.23.so[7f063617e000+1c0000]
Jan 10 02:26:25 xxxxxxx dockerd[5506]: time=“2019-01-10T02:26:25.020765635-05:00” level=warning msg=“Couldn’t run auplink before unmount /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt/ad9ab9225c557c10acf97aab3ae2f57fe56f0ad2fbae1798485b48b627a1f198” error=“signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)” storage-driver=aufs
```

We have noticed below error in the kernel log for a week prior to the incident

```
kernel: [2492882.553551] SLUB: Unable to allocate memory on node -1 (gfp=0x2080020)
kernel: [2492882.553556] cache: kmalloc-128(1480:8bdd4adeda1b84cc59cbd474d58a19bd2a8e97e63978e0d58f4bc7f3ce3a37e3), object size
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug report... otherwise what is your question?

Comment: I am trying to find the root cause for the incident happened in our environment. We were running docker ce 18.02 on this host and on 10-Jan-19, the container got deleted automatically and we have only these logs on the server. We are not able to correlate that incident with the errors in the log file, so seeking advise from experts

Comment: Is it bug ? does that cause container delete ?

Comment: A really terrible bug if so! Thanks for explaining. I'll take another look and maybe edit your question a bit later

Comment: I would need experts help here to analyze the logs and give a hint on what would have happened